# Constrained Maximum Flow Minimum Cost

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard, network-flow

Let $G=(V, E)$ be a directed network with a set $V$ of vertices and a set $E$ of edges. Two vertices are distinguished, $s,t$ which are the source and sink respectively. Each edge $(i, j)$ has an associated cost $c_{ij} \in \mathbb{Z}$ and a capacity $u_{ij} \in \mathbb{N}$. The objective is to achieve a flow of value $K$ from $s$ to $t$ and minimize the cost. The flow through each edge must be integral, is conserved at each vertex (except at $s$ and $t$) and doesn't exceed edge capacities. In addition, the total cost of the flow must also satisfy $\Sigma_{(i, j) \in E} c_{ij}x_{ij} \ge D$ where $x_{ij}$ is the flow through edge $(i, j)$ and $D \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Is this problem solvable in polynomial time or even in pseudo-polynomial time? If not, is there a constant factor approximation for the cost for general networks with a flow of value $K$?

I was able to find a paper describing a similar problem but with an upper-bound for the cost:  [A Capacity Scaling Algorithm for the Constrained Maximum Flow Problem](https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/citations/ADA459686), Ravindra K. Ahuja, James B. Orlin, Networks, 25(2), 1995.

Comment: @D.W. Thank you for your warning, I have edited the question. It's not possible to negate the costs and $D$ because the minimization property would return the solution $max_{cost}(G)$, it would become the smallest solution smaller than $-D$, the problem would instead become a maximization problem which would solve it, but it isn't the paper's focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be NP-hard, by a reduction from [subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

In particular, suppose we are given integers $a_1,\dots,a_n$ and target $D$.  Create a graph with two vertices, $s,t$. Add edges $s \to t$, where the $i$th edge has capacity 1, cost $a_i$, then add another edge $s \to t$ with capacity $n$ and cost $0$.  Set $K=n$.  Finally, find the minimum possible cost of all flows whose cost is $\ge D$ and value is $K$.  If the minimum possible cost is $D$, then you know there is a subset of $a_1,\dots,a_n$ that sums to $D$; otherwise no such subset exists.

There could still be a pseudo-polynomial time algorithm, FPTAS, or constant-factor approximation.

Comment: Thank you for your proof!